# Libertine with sfmath and siunitx in Beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, math-mode, siunitx, libertine

I am trying to use the Linux Libertine fonts with sfmath and siunitx package but it doesn't work with beamer class.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  test
 \end{frame}
\end{document
```

Error:

> Too many math alphabets used in version normal.

When I use the article or report class, no error appears.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
  test
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use it this way:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}%% do not define math settings by beamer itself
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  test $f(x)$
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Is there another way to extend the number of math alphabets? If I want to use other packages, such as chemfig and chemmacros, I get this error again.

Comment: Use `xelatex` or `lualatex` instead.